# Too many connections in MongoDB and Spark

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

My Spark Streaming application stores the data in MongoDB.

Unfortunately each Spark worker opening too many connections while storing it in MongoDB

[image]

Following is my code Spark - Mongo DB code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int numThreads = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
    String mongodbOutputURL = args[4];
    String masterURL = args[5];

    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF);
    Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF);

//    Create a Spark configuration object to establish connection between the application and spark cluster
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("AppName").setMaster(masterURL);

    // Configure the Spark microbatch with interval time
    JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(60*1000));

    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.set("mongo.output.uri", "mongodb://host:port/database.collection");

//    Set the topics that should be consumed from Kafka cluster
    Map<String, Integer> topicMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    String[] topics = args[2].split(",");
    for (String topic: topics) {
      topicMap.put(topic, numThreads);
    }

//    Establish the connection between kafka and Spark
    JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, String> messages =
            KafkaUtils.createStream(jssc, args[0], args[1], topicMap);

    JavaDStream<String> lines = messages.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {
      @Override
      public String call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple2) {
        return tuple2._2();
      }
    });

    JavaPairDStream<Object, BSONObject> save = lines.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, Object, BSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public Tuple2<Object, BSONObject> call(String input) {
            BSONObject bson = new BasicBSONObject();
            bson.put("field1", input.split(",")[0]);
            bson.put("field2", input.split(",")[1]);
            return new Tuple2<>(null, bson);
        }
    });
    // Store the records in database    
    save.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFiles("prefix","suffix" ,Object.class, Object.class, MongoOutputFormat.class, config);

    jssc.start();
    jssc.awaitTermination();
  }
```

How to control the no of connections at each worker?

Am I missing any configuration parameters?

**Update 1:**

I am using Spark 1.3 with Java API.

I was not able to perform `coalesce()` but I was able to do `repartition(2)` operation.

Now no of connections got controlled.

But I think connections are not being closed or not reused at worker.

Please find the below screenshot:

Streaming interval 1-minute and 2 partitions
[image]

Comment: It looks like you're creating 1 MongoDB connection per partition, Does the `save` DStream have 1000s of partitions? Perhaps try throwing a `.coalesce(20)` in before `saveAsNewAPIHadoopFiles` and see if that mitigates the issue.

Comment: @Ewan Thanks for the reply. please find the update 1 in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by using foreachRDD.

I am establishing the connection and closing it after every DStream.

```
myRDD.foreachRDD(new Function<JavaRDD<String>, Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd) throws Exception {
                rdd.foreachPartition(new VoidFunction<Iterator<String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Iterator<String> record) throws Exception {
                MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(server:port);
                DB db = mongo.getDB(database);
                DBCollection targetTable = db.getCollection(collection);
                BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject();
                while (record.hasNext()) {
                    String currentRecord = record.next();
                    String[] delim_records = currentRecord.split(",");
                    doc.append("column1", insert_time);
                    doc.append("column2", delim_records[1]);
                    doc.append("column3",delim_records[0]);
                    targetTable.insert(doc);
                    doc.clear();                        
                }
                mongo.close();                  
                }
                });
                return null;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try map partitions, which works on partition level instead of record level, I.e, task execute on one node will shares one database connection  instead of for every record.

Also I guess you can use a pre partition( not the stream RDD). Spark is smart enough to utilize this to reduce shuffle.